# Validity of a definition of continuity/discontinuity

Tags: continuity, definition

The definition of continuity as I know it is based on three conditions:

> We say $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=a$ if
>
> 1. $f(a)$ is defined
> 2. $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)$ exists
> 3. $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)$
>
> Otherwise, $f(x)$ is discontinuous at $x=a$.

All in all, this boils down to a simple conditional statement where continuity and discontinuity are negations of each other:  *if $f(x)$ is not continuous at $x=a$, then it is discontinuous at $x=a$, and if $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=a$, then it is not discontinuous at $x=a$.*

As suggested by [a comment in response to mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3751401/number-of-points-of-discontinuity-of-1-logx?noredirect=1#comment7715607_3751401) for a recent question, this definition of continuity is not correct.  That is, it is possible for a function to be neither continuous nor discontinuous at a point.  I would love to have this misunderstanding clarified so I can be more accurate in what I teach.

Comment: Once you pick a definition of continuity, there is no chance a function can be neither continuous nor discontinuous at a point. We can debate on the advantages and disadvantages of different definitions of both continuity and limit but there is no ambiguity once the definitions are set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function can only be continuous or discontinuous at points in its domain. So I think the comment responding to you is correct. Think of it in this way: Suppose you have a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$. It wouldn't make sense to say that $f$ is discontinuous at $i\in\mathbb{C}$, even though $\mathbb{R}\subset\mathbb{C}$. In the same way, if $f$ is a function on, say $[0, 1]$, then you can't say that $f$ is discontinuous at $x=10$ for example.

Having said that, I think this borders on a philosophical difference. The difference between "$f$ is neither discontinuous or continuous at $a$ if $f$ is not defined at $a$" and "$f$ is discontinuous at $a$ if it's not continuous at $a$" I think is unlikely to cause a major divergence in understanding for students.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends upon the definition that you are using, of course, but it seems to me more natural (and more common) to talk about a function $f$ being continuous or discontinuous at a point $a$ only if $a$ belongs to the domain of $f$ (that is, only if $f$ is defined at $a$). If $a$ belongs to the domain of $f$, then we say that $f$ is continuous at $a$ if the limit $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ exists and it is equal to $f(a)$. And we say that $f$ is discontinuous at $a$ if the limit $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ does not exist or if it exists but it is not equal to $f(a)$.

Comment: Then would you say that condition 1 is irrelevant?

Comment: I did not say that. Actually, I wrote that $f$ *is* defined at $a$. But I don't agree that $f$ is discontinuous at $a$ if it is undefined there.

Comment: That is precisely what I want clarified:  why is it incorrect to say that if a function $f$ is not continuous at $a$ then it is discontinuous at $a$?  Or maybe, what is the difference between the terminology "not continuous" and "discontinuous"?

Comment: Please keep in mind that *it is a matter of definition!* I am **not** saying that it is incorrect. I just find ridiculous to say, for instance, that the square root function is discontinuous at $-1$. How can it be discontinuous at $-1$ if $\sqrt{-1}$ does not even exist (in $\Bbb R$)? For me, continuity at $a$ means that if $x$ is close to $a$, then $f(x)$ is close to $f(a)$, and this doesn't even make sense if $f$ is undefined at $a$.